# how can i register TIME_TICK event broadcast receiver for android app even if app is running or not

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

i want to fire some event when system time matches the time stored in my database.I tried out this by using TIME_TICK broadcast receiver.when this receiver receive broadcast, i match my database entries with system time...but problem is that i can register this broadcast receiver from activity only...can't register from manifest file.so, when i close my app or remove it from recent apps list, this broadcast receiver stops working.
I refer the documentation that says that "TIME_TICK can only register from activity , not from manifest file". 
I also tried to find solution for my problem on stackoverflow and on google but i can't found proper answer.
so, if you know how to solve it then reply my question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to fire some event when system time matches the time stored in my database

Use `AlarmManager`.

> how can i register TIME_TICK event broadcast receiver for android app even if app is running or not

That is not possible, as it is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: I am beginner....so please give me any example or link for any example for using AlarmManager or give me hint

Comment: @JaydipKalkani: `AlarmManager` is covered in [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), [elsewhere in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), and in many books and courses on Android app development.

Comment: AlarmManager works but i am using 12 hours time format so, when i convert time into milliseconds, it goes in past because of 12 hours time format. how can i convert 12 hours time into correct milliseconds?

Comment: @JaydipKalkani: Um, add 12 hours if the time is PM. You might want to consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] showing how you are doing your conversion.